# How to add restriction to a restricted attribute in XSD

Tags: attributes, for-loop, xsd, restrictions

My requirement is like:
I need to validate an xml which has an element "Term" and its attributes as termType, ValueName, Value.
I need to add a restriction to termType such that, when I get the **termType** attribute value as "expression", the ValueName should only be IF or ELSE or THEN, and if the **valueName** value is "IF" the **value** should be "1" only.
How can I achieve this?

The xml looks like:

```
<Term termType="Input" value="97397D89-C044-47CC-8153-267CBBE71D29" valueName="PolicyType"/>
**<Term termType="expression" value="1" valueName="IF"/>**
<Term termType="mask" value="" valueName=""/>
```

Corresponding XSD I tried is:

```
<xs:simpleType name="termType">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="expression" />...
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="TermType">
 <xs:attribute name="termType" use="required" type="termType" />
 <xs:attribute name="value" use="required" type="xs:string" />
 <xs:attribute name="valueName" use="required" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of conditional restriction is a fairly common requirement but is not supported by XSD.